# Получение комментариев к media через instagram api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

При попытке получить комментарий к посту, возвращается ответ с комментарием пользователя, который получал access token, остальных комментариев в ответе нету.
Запрос выглядит так: 
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+mediaId+"/comments?access_token="+token`
С вытащенным медиа айди: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1162251688307718037_1824437940/comments?access_token=token`

Ответ выглядит так 
`{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"created_time":"1453069290","text":"текст_комментария","from":{"username":"username","profile_picture":"profile_pict","id":"id","full_name":"full_name"},"id":"1164752089812694405"}]}`

К другим медиа ответ пустой 
`{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}`, хотя комментарии точно есть. Это ограничения апи для песочницы или в запросе ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ограничение песочницы, так как получив `access_token` со стороннего сервиса с проверенным приложением и подставив его в запрос, стали показываться все комментарии и ко всем фотографиям.

При получении комментариев к не своим материалам с песочницы, отдавало ошибку:

> {"meta":{"error_type":"APINotFoundError","code":400,"error_message":"invalid
>   media id"}}

Comment: Все верно. Стоило внимательней читать документацию

`To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:

Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users
Reduced API rate limits`